# Kosual duality for crossed algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, duality-theorems

There are dualities of Koszul type

$$\mathsf{dgAlg} \longleftrightarrow \mathsf{dgCoalg}$$
$$\mathsf{dgLieAlg} \longleftrightarrow  \mathsf{dgSymmCoal}$$
$$\mathsf{dgSymmAlg}\longleftrightarrow \mathsf{dgLieCoalg}$$

For example, using bar/cobar constructions of the Lie analog.

Is there an analog crossed  Lie algebras $\stackrel{???}{\longleftrightarrow}$ crossed commutative algebras?

Comment: Dear Jim, can you point us to or add the definition of crossed Lie algebras and comm. algebras?